# Calling method while pushing into vector

Tags: c++

I'm using array now like:

```
weapons = new Weapon[nWeapon];
```

then I'm calling method from another class when adding:

```
weapons[0].createWeapon("Sword",1,2,3);
```

I want to rewrite it into vector but I don't know how to call that method in `vector` when calling `push_back`.

**Edit (code added):**

Weapon.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Item.h"

class Weapon : public Item {
public:
    Weapon();
    Weapon(Item i, int d);
    Weapon(string n, int c, int l, int d);
    Weapon(const Weapon* otherWeapon);
    Weapon(const Weapon& orig);
    virtual ~Weapon();

    void CreateWeapon(string n, int c, int l, int d);

    int GetDamage() const;
    void SetDamage(int d);

    void DisplayInfo();
private:
    int damage;
};
```

Weapon.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "Weapon.h"

Weapon::Weapon() {
    damage = 0;
    SetType(Item::Weapon);
}

Weapon::Weapon(const Weapon* otherWeapon) {
    SetName(otherWeapon->GetName());
    SetCost(otherWeapon->GetCost());
    SetLevel(otherWeapon->GetLevel());
    SetType(Item::Weapon);
    damage = otherWeapon->GetDamage();
}

Weapon::Weapon(const Weapon& orig) {
    SetName(orig.GetName());
    SetCost(orig.GetCost());
    SetLevel(orig.GetLevel());
    SetType(orig.GetType());
    damage = orig.GetDamage();
}

Weapon::Weapon(Item i, int d) : Item(i) {
    damage = d;
    SetType(Item::Weapon);
}

Weapon::Weapon(string n, int c, int l, int d) : Item(n, c, l) {
    damage = d;
    SetType(Item::Weapon);
}

Weapon::~Weapon() {
}

int Weapon::GetDamage() const {
    return damage;
}

void Weapon::SetDamage(int d) {
    if (d > 0)
        damage = d;
}

void Weapon::CreateWeapon(string n, int c, int l, int d) {
    SetName(n);
    SetCost(c);
    SetLevel(l);
    SetDamage(d);
    SetType(Item::Weapon);
}

void Weapon::DisplayInfo() {
    Item::DisplayInfo();
    cout << ", Damage: " << damage;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: ok I have
vector<Weapon> weapons(nWeapon);

now I want to call something like
weapons.push_back(createWeapon("Sword",1,2,3);
...

Comment: But `createWeapon` is apparently a method of already created weapon. You need to call constructor - maybe `Weapon("Sword", 1, 2, 3)` or a function (or static method) that returns `Weapon` objct.

Comment: You'll need to have something like `std::vector<Weapon*>` or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Weapon>>` or `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Weapon>>` for that.

Comment: @JacobLeet OK, so do that then?

Comment: @JacobLeet the member function "createWeapon" naming is misleading. Show us the weapon class please.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi added man

Answer (score 0):

The member function `CreateWeapon` is totally redundant and its name is nightmare for anyone who may maintain your code.

First, get rid of `CreateWeapon`.

Second, you may use it use `std::vector` like this:

```
std::vector<Weapon> weapons_vector;
weapons_vector.reserve(nWeapon); //this allocates memory but does not initialize (does not call the constructor).
```

now when you want to create new `Weapon`:

```
weapons_vector.emplace_back("Sword",1,2,3);
```

If `emplace_back` is not avaible:

```
weapons_vector.push_back(Weapon("Sword",1,2,3));
```

Comment: It "set" not "create". You should have "SetDamge", "SetName"... etc

Comment: sure but isn't better to call one function to set all attributes instead of 5 functions?

Comment: Why you want to set them all together after initializing the object? you have constructors that initialize them all. Why you would like change them all again?

Comment: emplace_back isn't available in my compiler... 
I used push_back and it gives me like 34 errors pointing me into compiler libraries..

Answer (score 0):

Your function, `createweapon` has confused *you*, because it categorically does *not* create a weapon, it simply populates one that already exists.

It is a *member function* which means you have to call it on an instance of an existing object (`Waepon w; w.CreateWeapon(...)`) - another reason it's a terrible name.

There are three ways you can use push_back in this case:

The sensible C++11 way:

```
std::vector<Weapon> weapons;
weapons.emplace_back("sword", 50, 1, 5);
```

`emplace_back` here takes parameters to pass to the *constructor* of Weapon.

The sensible pre-C++11 way:

```
std::vector<Weapon> weapons;
weapons.push_back(Weapon("sword", 50, 1, 5));
```

Or you could show the world that you hate life and do it this way:

```
std::vector<Weapon> weapons;
Weapon weapon;
weapon.createWeapon("sword", 50, 1, 5);
weapons.push_back(weapon);
```

If you don't just get rid of that function entirely, please rename it 'InitializeWeapon'?

Full example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

enum class ItemType {
    Weapon
};

struct Item {
    Item(std::string name, int cost, int level) : name_(name), cost_(cost), level_(level) {}
    virtual ~Item() {}

    void SetType(ItemType type) { type_ = type; }
    virtual void DisplayInfo() const {
        std::cout << name_ << ", " << cost_ << "c, L" << level_;
    }

    std::string name_;
    int cost_;
    int level_;
    ItemType type_;
};

struct Weapon : public Item {
    Weapon(std::string name, int cost, int level, int damage) : Item(name, cost, level), damage_(damage)
    {
        SetType(ItemType::Weapon);
    }

    virtual void DisplayInfo() const override {
        Item::DisplayInfo();
        std::cout << ", D" << damage_;
    }

    int damage_;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Weapon> weapons;
    weapons.emplace_back("sword", 50, 1, 2);
    weapons.push_back(Weapon("dagger", 60, 2, 3));

    for (auto& it : weapons) {
        it.DisplayInfo();
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << "weapons[0]: ";
    weapons[0].DisplayInfo();
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/ZyqVUu

Comment: used 
std::vector<Weapon> weapons;
weapons.push_back(Weapon("sword", 50, 1, 5));
and got 34 errors... damn it

Comment: @JacobLeet I don't know what those errors are, but I've added a complete example to the answer which you can see working online at ideone: http://ideone.com/QoCbM9

Comment: emplace_back isn't available in std so I used push_back and that gives me like 34 errors which points me into compiler libraries.. damn that for real

Comment: If you're using clang or gcc as your compiler, you can get emplace_back by adding the `-std=c++11` command line argument. If you're using visual studio you might consider upgrading to VS2013 or 2015 community editions (free).

Comment: I fixed errors but now it gives me segmentation fault when calling
weapons[i].DisplayInfo();

Comment: Are you making sure that `i` < `weapons.size()`? I added a DisplayInfo function to the example above: http://ideone.com/ZyqVUu

Comment: there is problem.. weapons is pointer to class Weapon as I said that's why I'm getting that error and can't fix it..

Comment: ok your ideone is working but I need to help
I'm writing out weapons in another class and I don't understand this:
for(auto& it:weapon).. I'm new in C++... thanks

Comment: @JacobLeet `for (auto& it: weapons)`: New in C++11, this is called range-based for. The thing after the : is a standard container with a begin and an  end. It will iterate over everything in the container. For each it will create a reference (`&`) called `it` and the `auto` asks the compiler to figure out what type `it` should be from it's knowledge of the container. It's equivalent to writing `for (Weapon& it : weapons)` - that is, each step of the loop, `it` will be the nth `Weapon` in the `weapons` vector.

Comment: @JacobLeet Another way of writing it would be `for (std::vector<Weapon>::iterator i = weapons.begin(); i != weapons.end(); i++) { Weapon& it = *i; ... }`

Answer (score -1):

```
// create new vector and fill it with nWeapon items (initialized with Weapon default constructor)
std::vector<Weapon> weapons(nWeapon);
// call method of weapon at index 0
weapons.at(0).createWeapon("Sword",1,2,3);
// or "direct access" without bound checking:
weapons[0].createWeapon("Sword",1,2,3);
```

If you want to start with empty vector and then fill it one by one:

```
std::vector<Weapon> weapons;
weapons.push_back(Weapon("Sword", 1, 2)); // if Weapon has such constructor
// or
weapons.push_back(create_weapon("Sword", 1, 2)); // a function that returns a Weapon
```

If Weapon doesn't have empty constructor:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Weapon>> weapons;
weapons.push_back(std::make_shared<Weapon>("Sword", 1, 2, 3));
// ^^^ similar to calling new Weapon("Sword", 1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: and in header file something like vector<Weapon*> weapons?

Comment: @JacobLeet You can put that `std::vector<Weapon> weapons` into header file. If you put `vector<Weapon*> weapons` into header file and then you use `weapon` as `vector<Weapon>` it will not work.

Comment: Defining global variables in header files? Enjoy your redefinition errors.

Comment: Well I hope it will be inside some `class` and not a global variable :)

Comment: sure but weapon is private member of Shop.h and it's also pointer to class Weapon so...

Comment: What? `Weapon weapon;` - `weapon` is not a pointer. `vector<Weapon>`  is  not a vector of pointers.

Comment: I'm lost now. I don't know what you are doing or trying to do. You've asked how to rewrite `weapons = new Weapon[nWeapon];` to vectors, I think you have two good answers here. When you work with vectors you should not work with pointers (unless they are smart pointers).

Comment: I'm lost too..
I have class Shop where in the header file is private member Weapon *weapons;
then I have that array which I wrote and it's working.. Just wanted to rewrite it into vector nothing else..

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that Weapon is a class or struct, you can do something like this:

```
vector<Weapon> weapons;//create a vector of weapon objects
Weapon wp;
wp.createWeapon("Sword",1,2,3);
weapons.push_back(wp);//add the object to the vector
```